# Windows 7 and Qemulator

Tags: windows, virtualization, lubuntu, qemu

Due to some issues I've had with VirtualBox, I recently switched to using Qemu, with the Qemulator GUI, and all has been well when playing with Linux virtual machines.

However, due to needs from my very-Microsoft-married school, I need to install Windows 7, but I'm having a problem. The Win7 installer is only seeing the virtual drive as 1GB in size and refuses to install on it. I initially used the "Auto" setting when creating the drive, but when that didn't work, I tried setting it explicitly to "Qcow2" after finding an old tutorial. That didn't work, either.

Is there a particular drive type that reports its size to Windows correctly? Or, is there a way I can tell Qemu to tell the VM that the size is different from its starting size (since the default is a dynamically expanding format)? The VM drives are stored on a 1TB drive with 3/4 of its space unused, so I'm not really concerned about drive space and a static-sized file could be used, if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your problem, but I successfully installed Win7 on qemu with this command:

> virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n win7 -r 2048 --vcpus=2 -f
>   win7.qcow2 -s 30 -c
>   win7.iso --vnc --noautoconsole
>   --os-type windows --os-variant win7 --accelerate --network=bridge:br0
>   --hvm

-n Name
-r Ram
-s Size in GB
-c Installation media

You might want to try this

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try when I get some time and get back to you. :)

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem, I had to adjust it to:
virt-install -n win7 -r 2048 --vcpus=2 -f win7.qcow2 -s 30 -c win7.iso --vnc --os-type windows --os-variant win7 --accelerate --network=user --hvm
and install both virt-install and virt-viewer (separately, for whatever reason virt-viewer doesn't install with virt-install) to get it to work, but it recognizes the size of the drive and is so far installing with no problem!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It launches the installer, but windows installer then says that a device driver is missing. It cannot see the disks. I've tried libvirt and raw and qcow2 disks. I'm stuck :(  I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an image to use like a hdd:

```
qemu-img create -o size=30GB win7.img
```

Then start the qemu to use the ISO as cdrom:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom path/to/win7.iso -hda win7.img
```

It will install windows, then, to start it:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda win7.img
```

I hope this will help you,

Arian